# What is the most efficient data structure for designing a PRIM algorithm?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, hashtable, minimum-spanning-tree

I am designing a Graph in c++ using a hash table for its elements. The hashtable is using open addressing and the Graph has no more than 50.000 edges. I also designed a PRIM algorithm to find the minimum spanning tree of the graph. My PRIM algorithm creates storage for the following data:

- A table named `Q` to put there all the nodes in the beginning. In every loop, a node is visited and in the end of the loop, it's deleted from Q.
- A table named `Key`, one for each node. The key is changed when necessary (at least one time per loop).
- A table named `Parent`, one for each node. In each loop, a new element is inserted in this table.
- A table named `A`. The program stores here the final edges of the minimum spanning tree. It's the table that is returned.

What would be the most efficient data structure to use for creating these tables, assuming the graph has 50.000 edges?

Can I use arrays?

I fear that the elements for every array will be way too many. I don't even consider using linked lists, of course, because the accessing of each element will take to much time. Could I use hash tables?

But again, the elements are way to many. My algorithm works well for Graphs consisting of a few nodes (10 or 20) but I am sceptical about the situation where the Graphs consist of 40.000 nodes. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see how this is answering my question...

Comment: 50K elements in a data structure is a trivial size for a computer.  You are worrying about a detail that doesn't matter.

Comment: @ManolisGrifoman I'm failing to see why you need half of the described data structures at all. And why and how a Graph is represented in a hash table? ... That's why I posted the link, because Prims algo is easier than what you want to do.

Comment: At some size **larger** than 50K, the N squared aspects of a crude solution get ugly.  Then you would want a "smart modify" version of a "priority queue".  So far as I understand, the `std` versions of priority queue don't support the modify operation you need.  Writing a better priority queue isn't hard, but isn't worth it for 50K elements.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. But, just out of curiosity, which data structure would I need if the elements were like 1.000.000.000?

Comment: Oh, thank you JSF for the information.

Comment: One of the computer meanings of the word "heap" is a type of data structure, one of whose uses is for priority queues.  The data structure you would want is a priority queue of pointers to objects which have indexes back into their position in the priority queue (updated by all internal acts of the priority queue).

Comment: deviantfan, my homework was aking for a Graph in which the elements are not stored in an array but rather sorted in a hashtable.

Comment: JSF, I understand. A queue in which every element points to a Graph link and it's prioritized by their weight, if I understand correct.

Comment: @ManolisGrifoman I'm still unsure how you're using the hash table...

Comment: @deviantfan then let me explain it to you with more detail. The homework is asking for an undirected weighted graph. One version of the graph as we know is consisted by an array in which every element is a head of a linked list while the rest of the elements of this list show this node's connections and are pointers to other elements of the array along with the weight of each individual element. 
So, instead of an array, I am asked to use a hashtable.

Comment: @ManolisGrifoman So currently you have no hash table yet? Ok, now I'm less confused. Because, if we mean the same thing, it's pretty much impossible (eg. collisions)

Comment: @ManolisGrifoman a "queue" not at all the same thing as a "priority queue" (in programming terminology).  For small element counts a "queue" can be used as a simpler alternative to a "priority queue".  But for very large element count, you really need the right data structure.

Comment: @deviantfan I have the hash table. Imagine it like a normal array, only it's never full. Besides that, it's exactly like a graph the way I described it earlier.  I designed the insert function of Graph. I am currently designing a way to find the minimum spanning tree in this Graph.

Comment: @JSF So, a priority queue is different from a queue? I thought that the priority queue is a normal queue except the fact that you are sorting an element while you are inserting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Since comments were getting a bit long):  The only part of the problem that seems to get ugly for very large size, is that every node not yet selected has a cost and you need to find the one with lowest cost at each step, but executing each step reduces the cost of a few effectively random nodes.

A priority queue is perfect when you want to keep track of lowest cost.  It is efficient for removing the lowest cost node (which you do at each step).  It is efficient for adding a few newly reachable nodes, as you might on any step.  But in the basic design, it does not handle reducing the cost of a few nodes that were already reachable at high cost.

So (having frequent need for a more functional priority queue), I typically create a heap of pointers to objects and in each object have an index of its heap position.  The heap methods all do a callback into the object to inform it whenever its index changes.  The heap also has some external calls into methods that might normally be internal only, such as the one that is perfect for efficiently fixing the heap when an existing element has its cost reduced.

I just reviewed the documentation for the std one
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue
to see if the features I always want to add were there in some form I hadn't noticed before (or had been added in some recent C++ version).  So far as I can tell, **NO**.  Most real world uses of priority queue (certainly all of mine) need minor extra features that I have no clue how to tack onto the standard version.  So I have needed to rewrite it from scratch including the extra features.  But that isn't actually hard.

The method I use has been reinvented by many people (I was doing this in C in the 70's, and wasn't first).  A quick google search found one of many places my approach is described in more detail than I have described it.
http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~chvatal/notes/pq.html#heap

Comment: Thank you, I will try it for practice.